# basic javascript - name search code

Tags: javascript, search

Hi i'm trying to write a basic name search program in javascript. I am learning atm so this is all very new to me. the code runs and instead of finding my name once it prints it out to the console 15 times -- there are 15 characters in the text variable but i have no idea how i am supposed to define this properly.

here is my code

```
var text = "blah james blah";

var myName = "james";

var hits = [];

for(var i=0; i<myName.length; i++) {
    if(text[i] ==='j'){
        for(j=i; j < myName.length+text.length; j++){
            hits.push('james');
        }
    }
}
if(i === 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
}
else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

thanks in advance
:) 
James

Comment: Yeah, it's Javascript

Comment: Fixed tag. This is Javascript, not Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKuSy/)

> indexOf: The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex,
>   returns -1 if the value is not found.

You can use this to see if a String contains what you are searching for.

```
var s = "blah james blah";
if ( (s.indexOf("james") > -1) ) {
alert("Found");
} else {
    alert("Not found");
}
```